# How to VBA caching xmlhttp request returned value?

Tags: excel, caching, vba, xmlhttprequest, user-defined-functions

I want to cache `xmlhttp` request 's returned value so as NOT to wait too long when calling hundreds of such request.

I have tried caching values in Array/Collection but when Excel closed and reopened later, all caches are lost!

**Update**

I call `myDemo()` 100 times in 100 cell. This is its VBA code

```
Function myDemo (text)
    url = "http://demo.namgivu.com/FIP/index.php?r=excelFunction/onSO00&text=" & text
    url = url & "&currentTime=" & Now

    'Call service
    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.xmlhttp")
    xmlHttp.Open "GET", url, False
    xmlHttp.Send
    result = (xmlHttp.responseText)

    myDemo = result
End Function
```

And here is [my excel file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60740207/cache-xmlhttp-request.xlsm). Excel must wait so long when I open it...

Comment: Since you want to have control over when the result is refreshed, you should probably not be using a UDF.  Switch it out for a sub which just updates the cell value directly.

Comment: Something in your demo file is making the UDF volatile.  So every edit or update results in every formula using the UDF being recalculated.  Try doing a dependency tree rebuild using CTRL + SHIFT + ALT + F9.

Answer (score 0):

You can't keep items in variables when Excel is closed. To keep the data, you need to write it somewhere whether that be a worksheet, database or somewhere else very much depends on what you are doing. As you are using a UDF, can't you copy > paste special > values over the top of the formulas to create static values?